# Jenkins: Archive Artifacts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins job executes concurrent builds and every job creates an artifact. For some reason, I'm not able to archive artifacts for all my concurrent job. Usually, I see the artifacts for the very last build, but the result is being inconsistent.

**Question:** How can I preserve the artifacts after all my concurrent jobs?

To archive the artifacts I use the post-build action which is called: "Archive the artifacts."

Comment: Related: [60651580](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60651580/16586783)

Comment: @ArunKumarB Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I'll try this solution later today!

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your builds, it uses same workspace and overrides artifacts.

you can create a folder inside your workspace with buildNumber and save the artifacts in that folder and don't use `deletedDir()` in your pipeline code or cleanup your workspace .